# Use Blender file in Unity with Blender 3.0.0

Tags: unity-game-engine, model, blender

long story short:
To use blender models in Unity you need to **install a Blender Version 2.X** since the (in Unity integrated) python script that converts the models doesn't support 3.X yet.

Edit: As it stands now Unity and Blender 3.0.1 and onwards work properly together.

(source: https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-issues-with-blender-3-0-version-reading-issue.1207444/)

---

Original Question:
I got a new PC and tried to **open** my **Unity (2021.1.5f) Project**, which uses blender models. When opening the project i got errormessages saying "Blender could not convert the .blend file to .fbx file" and when i hit play there were spawning a bunch of empty Gameobjects called "missing prefab (dummy)". Also not all models were missing. Only the blender files (i think).

So it looks to me, that there might be a problem with blender 3.0.0, which is the newest version to download. In the unity Forum the user "Kurt-Dekker" already is helping people indicating to a Python script in the UnityEditor Directory "**Unity-BlenderToFBX**" but i didn't find an updated script that fix the issue with blender 3.0.0.

In case anyone is getting similar issues, i solved the issue by **installing** an **older blender version** (i use 2.8).

Is there anyone who knows how to fix the script for blender 3.0.0? :)
Hope i could help someone bypassing the problem for now and have a good day

Comment: Unity just use a python script to convert blend files to fbx.
So what really happens is the Unity python script works with Blender 2.x. Because Blender 3.x is new you probably need to update the script by yourself.
the script is located for example:
C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.1.28f1\Editor\Data\Tools\Unity-BlenderToFBX.py

Comment: thx for ur response. Since i have no ressource right now to get into a new programming language i just installed blender 2.X as described. I posted this question for future person that come across this problem and might oversee that blender 3.X is the issue. If in the future there will be a fix of the python script i update the question.

Answer (score 1):

Just follow these simple steps:

1. Apply all transforms using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
2. Export it as FBX or OBJ
3. In the export settings, make sure that the "Apply Modifiers" checkbox is checked and that "Export Materials" and "Export Textures" options are selected if needed.
4. Click the "Export" button to export your model.

Once the export is complete, you can import the model into Unity by following these steps:

1. Open your Unity project and create a new GameObject to hold your imported model.
2. Click on "Assets" -> "Import New Asset" to open the file browser.
3. Navigate to the exported file and select it.
4. In the import settings, make sure that the "Import Materials" checkbox is checked if you exported materials along with your model.
5. Click the "Import" button to import your model.